# Animation when add or remove ImageOverlay in Leaflet API

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to animate the adding and removal of an `ImageOverlay` on my map. Basically, `TileLayer` has this `getContainer()` function which allows to retrieve the html element corresponding to the layer. I can then call a `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` function to animate it like so:

```
$(tileLayer.getContainer()).fadeOut(5000, function(){
    map.removeLayer(tileLayer);
});
```

I would like to reproduce the same behaviour with my `ImageOverlay`, but there are no functions that enable to get the image element ([leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay-addto)). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use can use the `_image` property of your `L.ImageOverlay` instance. It holds the reference to the actual image element and you can use the `leaflet-image-layer` class to put the element on `display: none`:

Stylesheet:

```
.leaflet-image-layer {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];

// Fade in   
var imageOverlay = L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
$(imageOverlay._image).fadeIn(5000);

// Fade out
$(imageOverlay._image).fadeOut(5000, function(){
    map.removeLayer(imageOverlay);
});
```

In action on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/CCbyZh?p=preview